# unable to upload file without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to upload a file using ajax without refreshing the page. (I tried using form element it works. but it redirects to the other page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Test File Upload </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
  <button id="submitbtn"> Upload </button>

</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbtn").click(function(){

    var property = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", property);

    $.ajax({
      url: "AjaxPhp.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      cache : false,
      contentType : false,
      processType : false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(testresponse){
        if(testresponse.success == true){
          alert(testresponse.messages);
        } else {
          alert(testresponse.messages);
        }
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

this is my php file... please help :) thank you so much!

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "learningdb") or die("connection failed");

if($_POST){

$target_dir = "testupload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){

  $sql = "INSERT INTO uploadfile(image) VALUES ('$target_file')";
  mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  $valid['success'] = true;
  $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Uploaded!";
} else {
  $valid['success'] = false;
  $valid['messages'] = "Something went wrong...";
}
echo json_encode($valid);
}
?>
```

How do I proceed whith the problem. using Ajax for file upload while avoiding page reload.

Comment: change button to `<button type="button" id="submitbtn">`

Comment: the element is already a button Desai. adding that attribute won't be necessary..

Comment: check the difference first

Comment: I tried, nothing happens... :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this,  prevent normal submission of the form.
Do this:

$("#submitbtn").click(function(e){
      e. preventDefault();

If that doesn't work,
Add:
 return false;

Just after the Ajax closing brace.

Apologies for the poor formatting.  I'm typing via mobile

Comment: actually sir, you just gave me a marvelous idea! Thank you so much. Ugh.. I know these kind of problem is basics for a good programmers like yourself. Thank you sir! Will update you if it works! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

1. In AjaxPhp.php file , Use isset other wise ajax will not work.

   if(isset($_POST)) {
   //code
   }

Rest all code is fine. Just add isset and it will solve the  problem

Comment: but based on my coding it still works without the isset... I'm not really the kind of theoretical guy when coding... but soon I will be! I'm just a beginner by the way. thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: Hey Christian,  just want to know your problem already solved , or you still facing any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

@Christian jay Bringino  here is how you can fix the issue. 
Firstly when you are using `var formData = new FormData();` it is very important to have `<form>` Tag because here i'm using query `submit` event.

Secondly it is not `processType : false,` it is actually `processData : false,`

HERE IS THE FULL ANSWERE

HTML CODE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Test File Upload </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="file_form">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" value="upload">
</form>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#file_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var property = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    formData.append("file", property);

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "AjaxPhp.php",
      data: formData,
      cache : false,
      contentType : false,
      processData : false,
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(testresponse){
        if(testresponse.success == true){
          alert(testresponse.messages);
        } else {
          alert(testresponse.messages);
        }
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

PHP code :AjaxPhp.php

Insisted of `if($_POST)` use `if($_FILES['file']['name'])`

### Note: If you inserting data given by the user then use `MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENTS`  against sql injection here is the link [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 minor changes I made to script added by @Christian jay Bringino, and it works well .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Test File Upload </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
  <button id="submitbtn"> Upload </button>

</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbtn").click(function(){

    var property = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", property);

    $.ajax({
      url: "AjaxPhp.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      cache : false, 
      contentType : false,
      processData : false, //change processType to processData 
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(testresponse){
        if(testresponse.success == true){
          alert(testresponse.messages);
        } else {
          alert(testresponse.messages);
        }
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

AjaxPhp.php  (I dont have the table with this database connection so  I comment it)

```
<?php
//$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "learningdb") or die("connection failed");

if(isset($_POST)){ //use isset

$target_dir = "testupload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){

  /*$sql = "INSERT INTO uploadfile(image) VALUES ('$target_file')";
  mysqli_query($con, $sql);*/

  $valid['success'] = true;
  $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Uploaded!";
} else {
  $valid['success'] = false;
  $valid['messages'] = "Something went wrong...";
}
echo json_encode($valid);
}
?>
```